# Default css editing?

Tags: css

I have put together a website for work, its in its beginning stages and I am still learning .NET Core / MVC.

I have tried everything to remove the white space and get my background to cover the entire page. Obviously I only have the style set for the opt-in component i have, but I do not see a `main.css` all i see is `vendor.css` and even if i go in there and change css to

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
background-size: cover;
```

the white space stays the same,

I've inspected the elements with the debug console and I can see that my component doesn't actually cover the whole page, yet I cannot find the element anywhere in my code that actually,
http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20180517-ahau-195kb

Here is my git project https://github.com/InnovationGB/EventOptIn

I am assuming that it gets compiled and its not actually in my code,

Edit:

I made this change to my _layout.cshtml

```
 <base href="~/" />
    <style>
        html {
            background: url('http://i.e.eastbay.com/wpm/100233/WebForms/EB_Event_Signup_1/FL_form-engraved_background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

This had the following result, I cannot figure where the padding is happening....
http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20180517-mj1p-120kb

Comment: Not related to asp.net core

Comment: Actually it is, because my project was made with asp.net core templates, which is relevant information when it comes down to determining where exactly my files are. Where exactly is a learning developer supposed to get questions answered when this website is full of the smartest people in the world who get upset with the dumbest things.

Comment: Someone who knows nothing about .net core is going to look at this question and say, "i dont know where the heckyour main.css is so how am i supposed to tell you"

Comment: @Bluestreak22 which template did you use? Vendor.css sounds like a SPA template. Angular? React? Vue?

Comment: @Marco I used the Angular Asp.netcore MVC Template, I have looked through every css file and theres nothing I have found, I've even tried excluding vendor.css from being applied and still get the white space.

Comment: Any chance you can upload your project without ciritical information to github, so we can clone it and see for ourselves?

Comment: Yeah sure thing.

Comment: The vendor.css basically contains mainly the rules from bootstrap. I assume this might be related to you overwriting some base rules from there, which bauses this

Comment: I just dont understand though, when I make the HTML {} css contain my background on my component.css file, it does not overwrite, which means its only applying it to that specific component, and the component gets placed ontop of the "main" page but I cannot see a main page or main css anywhere added git repo to main post @marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, 
so the reason you have those white bars is indeed bootstrap. Namely the `container-fluid` class:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```

So, go into your app.component.html and add a suitable id to that div:

```
<div class='container-fluid' id="wrapper">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add a rule to your add.component.css

```
#wrapper, .body-content {
    padding:0;
}
```

Getting rid of the white bar at the bottom is as easy as removing `margin-bottom: 20px;` from

```
<div class="overlay_header" style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                <h1 class="overlay_header_heading"><!–– Thanks For Signing Up!--></h1>

                <p style="color: #ffffff;"><a href="https://www.eastbay.com/customerserv/help:privacyPolicy/" target="_blank" title="View our Privacy Policy" style="color: #ffffff;">Privacy&nbsp;Policy</a> and <a href="https://www.eastbay.com/customerserv/help:terms/" target="_blank" title="View our Terms of Use" style="color: #ffffff;">Terms&nbsp;of&nbsp;Use</a></p>
</div>
```

If you still have HMR enabled, the changes should be immediately visible in the browser.

Comment: Damn I honestly did not even think that container-fluid had any .css applied to it, mainly because it was used by bootstrap in vendor.css right? Also I did remove the margin bottom from the overlay_header div but this div is only visible after submitting an input which is why i believe the bottom margin is still there, I will keep looking for where it is though, unless you have any other ideaS?

Comment: My issue I think actually stems from the size of the image! Thanks a ton for your help Marco you the man.

Comment: I was wrong, if I remove the image, and use background-color, there is still white space at the bottom, im playing around trying to figure where i need to put this,